# How to update contact email with JavaScript API?

Tags: contacts, api, javascript

I'm trying to update a contact and, especially, the email address. As far as I can tell using the API explorer, this is the correct JavaScript code for that:

```
            crmApi('Contact', 'create', {
          id: myContact.id,
          first_name: myContact.first_name,
          last_name: myContact.last_name,
          middle_name: myContact.middle_name,
          "api.Email": myContact.email
        })
```

It correctly updates the names, but not the email. Does anyone see what I have wrong?

Comment: have you tried to put "email" as the key?

Comment: "api.Email": myContact.email should be 
    "api.Email.create": myContact.email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways you can update email for contact

1. Using Email api with create action

   ```
   CRM.api3('Email', 'create', {"email": "aaa@asas.comsdsd",  "id": 201}).done(function(result) { // do something});
   ```
2. Using Email api with replace action

> ```
>   CRM.api3('Email', 'replace', {
>       "values": {"0":{"email":"asasa@asas.com","location_typ_id":"Home"}},
>       "contact_id": 203
>     }).done(function(result) {
>       // do something
>     });
> ```

3. Using Contact api with Email chain api

> ```
> CRM.api3('Contact', 'create', {
>   "id": 203,
>   "api.Email.replace": {"values":{"0":{"email":"assdfsfdsasa@asas.com","location_typ_id":"Home"}}}
> }).done(function(result) {
>   // do something
> });
> ```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: 3. gave me what I needed. Adding the values object solved my problem. Many thanks!

Comment: I could use some similar advise with Address chaining. This snippet (below) does what I need for email and phone, but not street_address. (No error, but nothing changes.) Is there different syntax I should use for address?

         crmApi('Contact', 'create', {
           id: myContact.id,
           last_name: myContact.last_name,
           "api.Email.replace": {"values":{"0":{"email":myContact.email}}},
           "api.Phone.replace": {"values":{"0":{"phone":myContact.phone}}},
           "api.Address.replace": {"values":{"0":{"street_address":myContact.street_address}}},

etc.

Comment: There is a limitation why people use 'replace' method to update email is it deletes all the emails before it creates one. So you have to make sure you pass all the emails in array that a contact has.

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses are in their own separate entity in the API named "Email". You would update the email address with that using the contact ID to connect the person to the email address.

Example from the API Explorer (from Civi 4.6):

```
CRM.api3('Email', 'create', {
  "contact_id": 1111,
  "email": "example@example.org"
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Is that the best practice when I'm trying to update a contact's info with a single Save button? Shouldn't I try to use the chain API pattern?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!